# SQLObject: How do I prevent a specific class from being cached?

Tags: sqlobject

SQLObject caching is very aggressive for me. Can I prevent one specific class from being cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[from the manual](http://www.sqlobject.org/SQLObject.html#using-sqlmeta):

```
class MyClass(SQLObject):

    class sqlmeta:
        cacheValues = False

    # column definitions, etc.
```